# Google API Returning Sampled Data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using the Google-Analytics API to query my analytics for data using the  [Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on) We then use the spreadsheet data in Google Data studio for a dashboard to display the data.

Everything has been going well for the last few months, however over the last 48 hours we have begun to receive sampled data when we query the API using the spreadsheet add on. This is undesirable for how we are using the data.

The total results that we were getting before being returned was about 1100 results. We have altered the date range of the query to be only 3 days whereas before we were querying since the start of the year.

Initially that worked and the results were no longer sampled. Then 24 hours later the data appears to be sampled again.

The documentation says the following regarding sampling for the free account:

> Analytics Standard: 500k sessions at the view level for the date range you are using

We are not using our analytics that heavily so I cannot understand why we would have hit the 500K limit?

It is also not clear to me what a "View Level" is? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.